# What is this feature doing when I activate it "Publishing Approval Workflow", and how to use it?

Tags: approval-process

I am using SharePoint 2013. What is this feature doing when I activate it "Publishing Approval Workflow", and how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

publishing approval workflow is designed specifically for publishing sites where the publishing of new and updated web pages is tightly controlled. In these kinds of sites, no new content can be published until it has been approved by every approver in the workflow.

Source: [Publishing approval workflows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/work-with-a-publishing-approval-workflow-HA102891575.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I have also a publishing site. Sow give me some scenario when this workflow is triggered?

Comment: have you read the article properly?

Comment: yes I did. I dont have these options in my publish site collection. I read now this: You may have noticed that the built-in publishing approval workflow is not available for publishing site collections; it’s only supported on publishing sites.